# Constructing Network Packets in JS

Tags: javascript, networking

I'm trying to write a program in JS that can change up properties of packets sent, such as their TTL. I've found ways to do so in Python with the socket library, but is there a way to do so in JS? I found the websocket library but I have yet to find a way online to do what I would like to do here.

Edit: For the infrastructure idea I have, it requires me to be able to manipulate the packets on both the client side and the server side. However, the main one I am trying to address right now is the client side

Comment: What platform?  And, I assume you're using Node.js?

Comment: The goal is to do this both on the client and server side. I would ideally be setting up a browser extension for the client and probably Node.js for the server. This way both could implement the protocols I would like to try out.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this in a browser.  I think at best, you could implement a proxy server in Node.  What's the use case?  What's the end goal?